# Property does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Suddenly my typescript is throwing an error whenever I try use header tags in my tsx files stating that

```
Property 'h1' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.  TS2339
```

It accepts all other tags div, span, section - basically anything else except for any of the the h1 through h6 tags

Here is the rest of the render component

```
      return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={styles.paper} variant='outlined'>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
       )
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eliya's suggestion resolved the issue

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && npm i
```